# Usage of "par la même occasion" vs "en même temps"?

Tags: usage, indications-de-temps

I understand both of these phrases to mean *at the same time,* but I'm unsure of how their exact meaning and usage varies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*En même temps* will stress the simultaneity of the actions

> Ils ont parlé en même temps.
>
> Il faut appuyer sur les touches <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd> et <kbd>delete</kbd> en même temps.

*Par la même occasion* will stress the opportunity. The second action might be within the first one or slightly shifted.

> Il a fait un discours et remercié ses collègues par la même occasion.
>
> Ils ont fait le plein d'essence et lavé les vitres par la même occasion.

Comment: This answer is  perfect.