# "By the same token" (signifiant de la même manière)

Tags: traduction, anglais, anglicismes

Le mot [token](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token) existe en français. Peut-on employer en français le mot token dans le contexte de l'extrait ci-dessous (tiré du livre The Physics of Hockey) ?

> Applying physics to hockey helps us understand how aspects of  the
>   sport work and lets us make use of that knowledge to improve  our
>   game. On the flip side, talking about hockey in a physics context may
>   promote interest in science for the public at large and, by  the same
>   token, help create a better scientific culture (which many  will agree
>   is somewhat lacking in our society). I know this from  experience, as
>   students in my freshman mechanics class usually become interested
>   when real-life examples are used, especially examples from hockey.
>   Applications such as these make abstract theories  come alive.

i.e. présentant une déclaration qui, selon la personne qui parle, est vraie pour les mêmes raisons que pour une déclaration précédente (du même coup, dans le même esprit, etc.)

Comment: **et, [par la même occasion](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18548/usage-of-par-la-m%C3%AAme-occasion-vs-en-m%C3%AAme-temps/18563)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le mot token n'existe pas en français. En tout cas pas pour le TLFi ou le Larousse.
Une page d'homonymie sur Wikipédia ne fait pas de ce mot un mot de la langue française... Donc pour répondre simplement à la question, non on ne peut pas.

Comment: Le mot *token* existe en tant que néologisme, dans les secteurs très niches où il a un sens précis, comme les cryptomonnaies. Au même titres que d'autres mots techniques (quasi) intraduisibles, comme *servlet*, *pipeline*, ... Dans l'extrait on est pas du tout dans ce cas là donc on traduira par un autre mot.

Comment: Tout existe. je pense que tu veux dire que le mot *token* est _utilisé_ dans des secteurs de niche. Et pour ce qui est de l'utilisation je pense, mais ça n'est qu'une opinion, que l'emploi du mot sans le traduire est plutôt dû à un aspect pratique. La documentation sera majoritairement en anglais, traduire ces mots très spécifiques rendrait la communication compliquée entre deux personnes parlant de la même chose mais l'une ayant un document anglais et l'autre un document dans une autre langue. Sinon effectivement dans l'extrait il suffit simplement de traduire par un autre mot.